# java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration

Tags: tomcat, jaas

Hi
I am using Bonita5.2 and the Tomcat6.0.19
I exported the application(which gives a war file and some config file and libraries) and deployed in the tomcat. When I run the application, after the login page, I get the error

```
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
    com.sun.security.auth.login.ConfigFile.(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
         .
         .
         .
         .
```

Before starting tomcat I run a bat file with the following content:

```
set BONITA_OPTS="-Dorg.ow2.bonita.environment=d:\Tomcat6.0\conf\bonita-environment.xml"
set LOG_OPTS="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=d:\Tomcat6.0\conf\logging.properties"
set SECURITY_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=d:\Tomcat6.0\conf\jaas-standard.cfg"
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOG_OPTS% %SECURITY_OPTS% %BONITA_OPTS%
```

I guess this error is because the jaas config file is not found. But I am sure about the paths I have mentioned.

What else could be that I am missing to configure for jaas?

Thanks

Comment: is tomcat running as a windows service?

Comment: No, Its not running as windows service

Comment: Now I started tomcat from the windows service too. but no changes in error.

Comment: Which file did you add the SECURITY_OPTS in ? Are you sure Tomcat's taken all the other settings like logging also?

Comment: I gave the path of jaas-standard.cfg file. How can check that other setting have taken by tomcat?

Comment: well, do they show up in catalina.out or console as part of the startup? otherwise change some setting in logging.properties (like WARN to DEBUG) and see if it is working

Comment: I made some changes in the logging.properties file but no error in the window of Tomcat Server. 
In log of the Tomcat one file is jakarta_service_20100927.log and there is also no error regarding the properties file.

Comment: It seems that looging.properties file is not working. I had over write the logging file of tomcat with the logging file given with the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve this problem. I needed to put the jaas cnfig file path in the file

```
JAVA_HOME\jre6\lib\security\java.security
```

Thanks

Comment: May I know how did you specify this path in the file? In which file?

Comment: Answer from Jon is better

Answer (score 8):

Specifying the jaas config file like so on the command line would work also:

`-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:/Apps/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/conf/jaas.config`

Answer (score 2):

I am using the Tomcat 6.0.13 extracted (not Windows service) version and I faced the similar problem.

To fix it, I simply added the the following option to `catalina.bat` file:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:/SecureLoginModule.conf" %LOGGING_CONFIG%
```

It worked for me.

--
Tks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String configFileLocation = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/jaas.config");
    System.err.println(configFileLocation);
    System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", configFileLocation);
```

in your servlet or JSP

Answer (score 0):

inside `catalina.bat`

under line :`okhome`

add the following line

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.security.auth.login.config=%CATALINA_HOME%/conf/jaas.config
```

It works for me. I have that error for past 2 days and thanks you for some else post in here